# Handling of TimerService in Weld-Junit

Tags: java, testing, jakarta-ee, weld-junit4

I'm trying to setup a Weld-JUnit4 Test for a JavaEE Bean which uses a TimerService. The Application runs in a Wildfly Application Server an So the TimerService is injected into the bean via `@Resource`Annotation.

In Weld-JUnit I have to bind Resources via:
`WeldInitiator.from(<Some class).bindResource(nameOfRessource, <TimerServiceMock>)`

But this doesn't work. The mock will not be injected.
So I tried `@Resouce(name = "myTimer")`in the JEE Bean. This doesn't work too.
So I tried `@Resouce(lookup = "myTimer")`in the JEE Bean. This works in my Testcase. But in ProductionCode this will change the lookupbehaviour. So it is no valid solution.

How it is possible to Mock the TimerService in a WeldJunitTest? Is there any kind of default lookup for the java.ejb.TimerService?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

EJB Spec states

> 16.14 TimerService References
>
> The container must make the TimerService interface available either through injection using the Resource annotation or in JNDI under the name **java:comp/TimerService**, in addition to through the EJBContext interface. The authenticationType and shareable elements of the Resource annotation must not be specified.

So it should work if you use that name with the lookup attribute.

Alternatively:

> 16.2.2 Annotations for Environment Entries
>
> [...]
>
> - A field of the bean class may be the target of injection. The field must not be final. By default, the name of the field is combined with the name of the class in which the annotation is used and is used directly as the name in the bean’s naming context. For example, a **field named myDatabase** in the class MySessionBean in the package com.acme.example would correspond to the JNDI name **java:comp/env/com.acme.example.MySessionBean/myDatabase**. The annotation also allows the JNDI name to be specified explicitly.

So you can also bind the JNDI-name that corresponds to the name of the field. It would allow you to get away with even less overhead in the EJB itself, but at the cost of breaking the test whenever you rename the field.